# Inter-rater agreement (Fleiss' Kappa, Krippendorff's Alpha etc) Java API?

Tags: math, machine-learning, nlp, classification, ontology

I am working on building a Question Classification/Answering corpus as a part of my masters thesis. I'm looking at evaluating my expected answer type taxonomy with respect to inter-rater agreement/reliability, and I was wondering: Does anybody know of any decent (preferably free) Java API(s) that can do this?

I'm reasonably certain all I need is Fleiss' Kappa and Krippendorff's Alpha at this point.

Weka provides a kappa statistic in it's evaluation package, but I think it can only evaluate a classifier and I'm not at that stage yet (because I'm still building the data set and classes).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find an existing Java API in time for my research, so I ended up implementing both Fleiss' Kappa and Krippendorff's Alpha myself. Preliminary results for our research can be found [in this paper](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1882992.1883077&coll=DL&dl=GUIDE&CFID=10179128&CFTOKEN=61994919).

Comment: In case you still need them, here are some implementations of Fleiss' Kappa in several languages: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Statistics/Fleiss'_kappa

Answer (score 1):

I ported a matlab implementation of Fleiss' kappa to Python/numpy.

http://code.google.com/p/hydrat/source/browse/src/hydrat/common/fleiss.py

It is not difficult to implement, perhaps you could port it to Java yourself.

Comment: I guess I should have updated this at some point in the last year or so...I actually did end up implementing Kappa and Alpha in Java, but thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Check QDAP (Pittsburg University) Open Source code.